# Distributions over sequences of non-independent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: conditional-probability, random-variable, independence, bernoulli-distribution

I'm modelling the generation of some sequences using random variables for generation of their components. For instance, the probability of generating the sequence $ABC$ should depend entirely on $P(A) = a$, $P(B) = b$ and $P(C) = c$. I don't want to say $P(ABC) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$ because that suggests longer sequences are less likely to be generated (which is not the case). In other words, $P(A)$ is not independent of $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ - if $A$ is generated that makes it more likely that $B$ and $C$ will be. One way to do this would be saying $P(ABC)$ is the arithmetic mean of $a$, $b$ and $c$. But my intuition is that the geometric mean would be more sensible. Is there a justification for either of those, or another model?

Comment: If this are generated sequentially, maybe a Markov chain model? Anyhow, it could help if you gave more context---what does this symbols represent, to what use will you put a model?

Comment: "One way to do this would be saying P(ABC) is the arithmetic mean of a, b and c."  -- I don't think this makes sense in general, since you could easily have $P(ABC)>P(A)$, which doesn't make any sense.